# React-bootstrap Component Font Size

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I wanted to manually changed the font size for a ReactJS project. I tried to add something like

```
* {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

and that works with everything that is a plain text. However, every component from `react-bootstrap` (e.g., DropdownButton, Panel) remains a large font size. Thus, what is the correct way to change the font size for those `react-bootstrap` components to the same as for other plain text? Inline styling works but I would like the changes to apply to a .css file. Thanks!

Edit: Panel Header code snippet:

```
  <Panel>

    <Panel.Heading>
      <Panel.Title>
         title here 
      </Panel.Title>
    </Panel.Heading>
  ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `* {font-size: 10px;}`

Comment: Try body{font-size:10px ! important}

Comment: @VitoMadio Nothing changed :(

Comment: @RedaMeskali I changed the root (App.css) to this and partially that works. However, the font-size for Button and Panel title are still large. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

To change the font-size of **all** text in your project, use

```
* {font-size: 10px;}
```

Alternatively, you can pass a style prop to a component, EX: `<Panel.Body style={{fontSize: 10}}`

Comment: Hi Conrad, I changed the root css to this one. Partially that works but Panel title and Button still remain very large. See my edit for a code snippet.

Comment: Hello, have you tried using `<Panel.Title style={{fontSize: 10}}`?

Comment: Although you probably have done this, i'd import the .css file directly in the component file you are using.

Comment: That works but I am trying to put styles to css files. Since the font is sort of a global setting, I am looking a way that does not require me to do the manually in-line setting. And yes, I am importing the css file. I have other configs for different kinds of components so that should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you can add `style={{fontSize:"10px"}}` inside the jsx button or any element, this will directly apply to your jsx element and bootstrap default won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p className="fw-bold">Bold text.</p>
      <p className="fw-bolder">Bolder weight text </p>
      <p className="fw-normal">Normal weight text.</p>
      <p className="fw-light">Light weight text.</p>
      <p className="fw-lighter">Lighter weight text</p>
/* Or text formatting like a - h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 */
<p className="fs-1">H1 text</p>
      <p className="fs-2">H2 text</p>
      <p className="fs-3">H3 text</p>
      <p className="fs-4">H4 text</p>
      <p className="fs-5">H5 text</p>
      <p className="fs-6">H6 text</p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).